# Import flink-scala api cause error

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I am trying import flink scala api on build.sbt as following:

```
name := "flink_stream"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-scala
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % "1.4.0"
```

and it complains:

```
sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.flink#flink-scala_2.12;1.4.0: not found

at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.resolveAndRetrieve(IvyActions.scala:331)

at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$updateEither$1(IvyActions.scala:205)

at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.$anonfun$withModule$1(Ivy.scala:243)

at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.$anonfun$withIvy$1(Ivy.scala:204)

at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.sbt$internal$librarymanagement$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:70)

at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:77)

at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)

at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)

at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)

at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)

at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)

at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)

at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)

at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)

at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)

at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:77)

at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:199)

at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:196)

at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:242)

at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:190)

at sbt.librarymanagement.ivy.IvyDependencyResolution.update(IvyDependencyResolution.scala:20)

at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:56)

at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:46)

at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:99)

at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:68)

at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$19(LibraryManagement.scala:112)

at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:224)

at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:112)

at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:95)

at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:149)

at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:126)

at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask$5(Defaults.scala:2381)

at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)

at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:39)

at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:66)

at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:262)

at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)

at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:271)

at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:262)

at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:174)

at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:36)

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.flink#flink-scala_2.12;1.4.0: not found

at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.resolveAndRetrieve(IvyActions.scala:331)

at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$updateEither$1(IvyActions.scala:205)

at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.$anonfun$withModule$1(Ivy.scala:243)

at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.$anonfun$withIvy$1(Ivy.scala:204)

at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.sbt$internal$librarymanagement$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:70)

at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:77)

at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)

at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)

at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)

at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)

at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)

at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)

at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)

at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)

at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)

at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:77)

at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:199)

at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:196)

at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:242)

at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:190)

at sbt.librarymanagement.ivy.IvyDependencyResolution.update(IvyDependencyResolution.scala:20)

at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:56)

at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:46)

at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:99)

at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:68)

at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$19(LibraryManagement.scala:112)

at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:224)

at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:112)

at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:95)

at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:149)

at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:126)

at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask$5(Defaults.scala:2381)

at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)

at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:39)

at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:66)

at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:262)

at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)

at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:271)

at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:262)

at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:174)

at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:36)

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

(update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.flink#flink-scala_2.12;1.4.0: not found

(ssExtractDependencies) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.flink#flink-scala_2.12;1.4.0: not found

Total time: 2 s, completed Jan 27, 2018 11:52:30 PM
```

The project setting is:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://flink.apache.org/faq.html#what-are-the-prerequisites-to-use-flink) states, Flink's Scala API depends on Scala 2.11; Scala 2.12 is not supported as of Flink 1.4.0. Change your Scala version to a 2.11 release:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
```